# Storing a directed, weighted, complete graph in the GAE datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a directed, weighted, complete graph with 100 vertices. The vertices represent movies, and the edges represent preferences between two movies. Each time a user visits my site, I query a set of 5 vertices to show to the user (the set changes frequently). Let's call these vertices A, B, C, D, E. The user orders them (i.e. ranks these movies from most to least favorite). For example, he might order them D, B, A, C, E. I then need to update the graph as follows:

```
Graph[D][B] +=1
Graph[B][A] +=1
Graph[A][C] +=1
Graph[C][E] +=1
```

So the count Graph[V1][V2] ends up representing how many users ranked (movie) V1 directly above (movie) V2. When the data is collected, I can do all kinds of offline graph analysis, e.g. find the sinks and sources of the graph to identify the most and least favorite movies.

The problem is: how do I store a directed, weighted, complete graph in the datastore? The obvious answer is this:

```
class Vertex(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class Edge(db.Model):
    better = db.ReferenceProperty(Vertex, collection_name = 'better_set')
    worse = db.ReferenceProperty(Vertex, collection_name = 'worse_set')
    count = db.IntegerProperty()
```

But the problem I see with this is that I have to make 4 separate ugly queries along the lines of:

```
edge = Edge.all().filter('better =', vertex1).filter('worse =', vertex2).get()
```

Then I need to update and put() the new edges in a fifth query.

A more efficient (fewer queries) but hacky implementation would be this one, which uses pairs of lists to simulate a dict:

```
class Vertex(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    better_keys = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
    better_values = db.ListProperty(int)
```

So to add a score saying that A is better than B, I would do:

```
index = vertexA.index(vertexB.key())
vertexA.better_values[index] += 1
```

Is there a more efficient way to model this?

Comment: Is your graph fixed at this size? Could you not store the whole thing in a single entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem with a minor modification to the first design I suggested in my question.

I learned about the [key_name](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities.html#Kinds_IDs_and_Names) argument that lets me set my own key names. So every time I create a new edge, I pass in the following argument to the constructor:

```
key_name = vertex1.name + ' > ' + vertex2.name
```

Then, instead of running this query multiple times:

```
edge = Edge.all().filter('better =', vertex1).filter('worse =', vertex2).get()
```

I can retrieve the edges easily since I know how to construct their keys. Using the [Key.from_path()](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html#Key_from_path) method, I construct a list of keys that refer to edges. Each key is obtained by doing this:

```
db.Key.from_path('Edge', vertex1.name + ' > ' + vertex2.name)
```

I then pass that list of keys to get all the objects in one query.